# How to enable TLS 1.2 and disable TLS1.0 and TLS1.1 with IIS on Windows server

Tags: windows, windows-server, tls

TLS 1.0 and 1.1 have been deprecated by the Internet Engineering Task Force (IETF) as of March 25, 2021.
How to enable TLS 1.2 and disable TLS1.0 and TLS1.1 with an old Windows server(2008/2012~) on IIS.

Comment: You don't actually specify you are using IIS.  Are you using that web server service?

Comment: @Ramhound thanks a lot, I've changed the article content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy way to do this
Step: 1. [Download IIS Crypto GUI](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/Download)
[image]

Step: 2. Unclick 1.0 and 1.1 and click 1.2 and then reboot
[image]

Step: 3. [TLS checker](https://www.cdn77.com/tls-test/result?domain=https%3A%2F%2Ftestbed.getac.com.tw)

[image]